# How Do I have the text in the text box get printed in the console?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

OK, So i just started learning how to code in python and I really like making gui with tkinter. I have run into a problem i just cannot fix! hopefully someone will be able to help.

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

text_box = tk.Text()


text_box.pack()

window.geometry("700x500+50+60")

window.title('Welcome!')



label = tk.Label(
     text="Hello, Welcome to my first app!",
     foreground="white",
     background="black"
)

button = tk.Button(
        text="click me!",
        width="25",
        height="5"
)




button.pack()
label.pack()



window.mainloop()
```

so i just need to have whats in the textbox print into console when i press the button.

Comment: Do you know where i would put this? do i just need to put it wherever?

Comment: what have you done to print it to the console?

Comment: I havent gotten it to print into the console

Answer (score 0):

Use `print(text_box.get(1.0, 'end-1c'))`. The `1.0` means "line 1.character 0". The `'end-1c'` means "end of `Text` minus 1 character". The entire thing encompasses the range you want to return (inclusively). You want to omit the last character because, `Text` widgets automatically have a newline character in them ~ unless you want that character in your print, then just use `'end'`.

The below example is the OOP implementation of your app. It is heavily commented to give you direction.

```
import tkinter as tk


#extend root
class App(tk.Tk):
    #application constants
    WIDTH, HEIGHT, X, Y, TITLE = 700, 500, 50, 60, 'Welcome'

    #class constructor
    def __init__(self):
        #super()
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        #force this row and column to take up as much space as possible
        #affects textfield and welcome
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        
        #same thing as your "text_box"
        self.textfield = tk.Text(self)
        self.textfield.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='nswe')
        
        #same thing as your "label" but given a more descriptive name
        self.welcome = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to my first app!", fg="white", bg="black")
        self.welcome.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nswe')
        
        #same thing as your "button" but given a more descriptive name, and a purpose
        #note: width and height are in characters, not pixels ~ same for Label and Text
        self.print_btn = tk.Button(self, text="print", width=5, height=1, command=self.toConsole)
        self.print_btn.grid(row=1, column=1)
        
    def toConsole(self):
        #how to send text from a textfield to the console
        print(self.textfield.get(1.0, 'end-1c'))
        
        
#properly initialize your app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.title(App.TITLE)
    app.geometry(f'{App.WIDTH}x{App.HEIGHT}+{App.X}+{App.Y}')
    app.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks man i guess mine just wasnt made to where you can do that

Comment: @LiamCHTML - You could easily do the above with yours. You are eventually going to get better and will stop structuring your code the way you are. I don't believe in "fixing starter code". I believe in showing starters how to do it right. When I started (25 years ago) I skipped all the "absolute beginner" books. It was hard. It was very hard. It was also worth every headache and sleepless night. I'm just trying to help you have some headaches and sleepless nights.